# Jenkins Pipeline - upload artifacts to s3 with build parameters

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline

I'm building multiple branches, and I have created a build parameter (String parameter) for branch. So my artifacts should get upload to specific branch based on the parameter I pass:

```
s3Upload(file:'target/test-ear-1.0.ear', bucket:'test/$BRANCH', path:'').
```

But `$BRANCH` or `${BRANCH}` is not working. Its copying to the path like this `test/$BRANCH`. I'm expecting it should upload to `test/dev`.

Does anyone have hints on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying it within double quotes.

```
bucket: "test/${BRANCH}"
```

Answer (score 1):

It [should be](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#additional-environment-variables) `$BRANCH_NAME` or `${env.BRANCH_NAME}`.

Comment: Tried the both options and both copying literally as test/$BRANCH_NAME & test/${env.BRANCH_NAME}

Comment: Try using doublequotes

Comment: It worked with double quotes, but did not use the $BRANCH_NAME or ${env.BRANCH_NAME}. $BRANCH_NAME throws missingproperty exception and ${env.BRANCH_NAME} returns null. So the Build Parameter (String Parameter) worked with Double quotes. Thank you @madhead